# Laravel 5 Auth: User must implement CanResetPassword interface

Tags: laravel-5

I've successfully implemented Laravel's Auth for Registration, Login and Logout. However, I'm having quite a bit of difficulty resolving the following error trying to implement the password reset functionality.

```
Error: User must implement CanResetPassword interface.
```

I believe my User class is configured properly:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, 
                                    CanResetPasswordContract {
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    ...
}
```

I'm not using Eloquent, so I have the following in config/auth.php:

```
'driver' => 'database'
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting the "User must implement CanResetPassword interface" error?

Thanks much!

EDIT: Adding Stack Trace:

```
UnexpectedValueException in PasswordBroker.php line 237: 
User must implement CanResetPassword interface .

in PasswordBroker.php line 237
at PasswordBroker->getUser( array('email' => 'admin2@beaudini.com')) in PasswordBroker.php line 81
at PasswordBroker->sendResetLink (array('email' => 'admin2@beaudini.com'), object(Closure)) in Facade .php line 217
at Facade::__callStatic('sendResetLink' , array(array('email' => 'admin2@beaudini.com'), object(Closure))) in ResetsPasswords.php line 35
at Password::sendResetLink(array ('email' => 'admin2@beaudini.com'), object(Closure)) in ResetsPasswords .php line 35
at PasswordController->postEmail (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PasswordController), 'postEmail'), array( object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('postEmail', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher .php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call (object(PasswordController), object(Route), 'postEmail') in ControllerDispatcher .php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate \Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 41
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array (object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack (object(PasswordController), object(Route), object(Request), 'postEmail') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch (object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController', 'postEmail') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object (Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object< /em>(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object (Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http \{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 49
at Debugbar->handle(object (Request), object(Closure ))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object (Request), object(Closure ))) in Pipeline .php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession .php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession ->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62< /a>
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline .php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse .php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse ->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array (object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle (object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline .php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode .php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode ->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure }(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter (object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object( Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Are you implementing all of the methods the interface? There's only one, getEmailForPasswordReset(), do you have that implemented in your User class? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/CanResetPassword.php

Comment: No, I haven't implemented that method, or any in the Authenticatable interface. I believe I'm using the default methods in the traits.

Comment: Oh, duh, I missed that you had both the traits and the interfaces. What are you trying to do that fails? Post the full stack trace

Comment: Stack Trace added as edit in OP above. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, forgot to add: I'm clicking the "Send Password Reset" link on the "Reset Password" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow your stack trace.

PasswordBroker.php line 237

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L237

Fails because `DatabaseUserProvider`'s `retrieveByCredentials` returns a `GenericUser` object, **not** your User class object.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php#L99

What this means, basically, is that the password reminder functionality that Laravel comes with is only supported by the `eloquent` auth driver. You can't use it with the `database` driver. Your options are

1. switch to Eloquent
2. build out password resets by yourself, or
3. [add your own custom auth driver](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-authentication-drivers)

Inside of a service provider (AppServiceProvider, or create a new one):

```php
Auth::extend('custom', function($app) {
    return new CustomUserProvider($app['database.connection']);
});
```

It might be as simple as extending the database user provider and overriding `getGenericUser` to use your class instead.

```php
class CustomUserProvider extends \Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider
{
    protected function getGenericUser($user) {
        if ($user !== null) {
            return new \App\User((array) $user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did see the "PasswordBroker.php line 237" in the Trace and looked at that function.

From what I've read, I thought that the Auth Scaffolding worked with 'database.'

I'll try creating the Custom Auth driver you mentioned above, as it's took late to switch to Eloquent.

Thanks, and will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Quick Clarification... On the Custom Auth Driver page, it says: "If you are not using a traditional relational database to store your users, you will need to extend Laravel with your own authentication driver." I'm using MySQL, and it is working fine with Registration and Login.  I would think Password Reset would work with MySQL as well. No?

Comment: @RobertFrenette everything Auth related works except password reminder stuff. If you look at the GenericUser class you'll see that it implements `Authenticatable` but not `CanResetPassword`. Kind of annoying since CanResetPassword just has the one "get email" method

Comment: @RobertFrenette the "not using a traditional relational database" is just one example of why you'd need to extend it. This is another example

Comment: andrewtweber - wanted to get back to you. I wasn't having any luck with a custom auth driver, so I decided to roll-my-own Password Reset functionality. Thanks for weighing in on this.

Comment: @RobertFrenette thanks for the update, I was wondering. I'll see if I can get it working, if I have some time this week

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem in laravel 5.2, and I found a solution like as:

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Eloquent;
    // use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as
               CanResetPasswordContract;

    class User extends Eloquent implements
             Authenticatable,CanResetPasswordContract        

     {
         use AuthenticableTrait,CanResetPassword;
         .......
         .......
     }
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me, I was missing


`use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;`


on my class bellow after AuthenticatableContract


`class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract,CanResetPasswordContract`

Comment: Simply implementing CanResetPassword worked perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

The below should work in Any Model You Created

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;



class customer extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,CanResetPasswordContract
{
        //protected $primaryKey = 'customerId';
        use AuthenticableTrait,CanResetPassword;
        use ValidatesRequests;
    protected $fillable=['name','email','password','country','favorite','gender','image'];
        protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

hope it helps